# Error linking dpdk application in VS 2019 - where to find the missing per_lcore__lcore_id symbol

Tags: clang, visual-studio-2019, dpdk

I am trying to compile dpdk helloworld in VS 2019 on windows platform.

I have installed clang itself and clang kit for 2019 (Edit custom clang location to point to the right clang version recommended by dpdk). The dpdk libraries were built meson and ninja.

However when I am trying to compile the application in VS2019 it throws

```
------ Build started: Project: dpdk, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
lld-link : error : undefined symbol: per_lcore__lcore_id
>>> referenced by C:\include\rte_lcore.h:78
>>>               x64\Debug\dpdk.obj:(unsigned int __cdecl rte_lcore_id(void))
Done building project "dpdk.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have included all dpdk *.dll.a libraries in linker "Additional Dependencies" option including the librte_eal.dll.a

Where this symbol should be taken from?

UPDATE:
dpdk version - dpdk-21.05
clang version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)

I can build the dpdk-helloworld.exe (for some reason it is the only one which is built)
with

```
cd <ROOT>/build
meson configure -Dexamples=helloworld
ninja
```

Output of nm on

```
λ nm librte_eal.dll.a --defined-only | grep per_lcore__lcore_id     
0000000000000000 I __imp___emutls_v.per_lcore__lcore_id             
0000000000000000 I __nm___emutls_v.per_lcore__lcore_id
```

It cannot be run though and exits with following output

```
C:\utils\dpdk\dpdk-21.05\build\examples                                             
λ dpdk-helloworld.exe                                                               
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)                                                            
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes                                                          
EAL: Multi-process support is requested, but not available.                         
EAL: Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019  is required for memory management           
EAL: FATAL: Cannot access Win32 memory management                                   
EAL: Cannot access Win32 memory management                                          
PANIC in main():                                                                    
Cannot init EAL                                                                     
7: [<unknown> (RtlUserThreadStart+0x21)[0x7FFC0D821760]]                            
6: [<unknown> (BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14)[0x7FFC0D6B84C0]]                           
5: [<missing_symbols>]                                                              
4: [<missing_symbols>]                                                              
3: [<missing_symbols>]                                                              
2: [<missing_symbols>]                                                              
1: [<missing_symbols>]                                                              
                                                                                    
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.       
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: can you please update 1) the dpdk version that is in use, 2) definition for `per_lcore_lcore_id` is under `rte_per_lcore.h`, 3) variable is to be stored per thread local variable 4) Did you install the mentioned clang-llvm http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/windows_gsg/build_dpdk.html#option-1-clang-llvm-c-compiler-and-microsoft-msvc-linker version? 5) can you manually build the application without VS2019?. I am able to build DPDK and application with mingw64

Comment: @VipinVarghese done

Comment: from the current logs this looks like more of large page configuration issue. Can you rerun the application as `dpdk-helloworld.exe --no-huge`. If this runs then you have issue in large page setting. Please update with the result

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks, However the issue is not compiling the dpdk with meson/ninja but setting project in VS2019.  I just added the information to show that helloworld application can be built (event if not running correctly) with meson but fails to compile in VS.

Comment: based on your helloworld run it looks like you have compiled the same. The error reported in helloworld `FATAL: Cannot access Win32 memory management ` which means application is not able to access the libraries in Windows for large page and access. Hence I requested you to rerun the application with `--no-huge` to confirm if it is indeed memory library access is the issue. But based your current comment you assume `I am asking about compilation` which I humbly would like to correct that it is wrong assumption. Will wait for your updates.

Comment: can you share the result for `1) pkg-config --static --libs --cflags libdpdk` and `2) running helloworld with option --no-huge`. As mentioned in my comments `the error per_lcore__lcore_id mostly due the compiler or linker flags not passing the right sequeuence`. With the result of `pkg-config` try rebuilding  the helloworld example manually.

Comment: I waiting for your update on `pkg-config` result vs `the custom links you have updated for VS 2019` and result of manually linking *helloworld with pkg-config results rather than VS2019 custom linking*. Please note definition for RTE_DEFINE_PER_LCORE is present in `rte_per_lcore.h` . Hence linking with `lib/eal/include/` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Windows DPDK as of release 21.08 runs on Windows server 2019 instance for both Host and VM. As per the error log `EAL: Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019  is required for memory management`, it looks like either the Platform OS is not correct or the Windows Development Kit SDK version is not the right version.

Since the option `--no-huge` allocates from HEAP (malloc) area works without any issues, the issue could be platform OS ***because windows release to support 2MB huge pages and require VirtaulAlocc API defined in memory.h***.

Note: there is also issue with manual linking with pkg-config from DPDK version 20.11 to 21.08. Hence shared in comments `Please note definition for RTE_DEFINE_PER_LCORE is present in rte_per_lcore.h . Hence linking with lib/eal/include/ is required.`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several questions going on here.  I'll answer only your first.

The DPDK Windows port doesn't currently support DLLs because the Windows platform and linker do not support __declspec(export) of _Thread_local variables.

Your only option is to statically link the application to the DPDK EAL and other DPDK libraries.  You'll have to add the actual static archives to your link line instead of the import libraries for the DLLs.  Both library types have a .lib extension which is confusing but I believe the meson build installs the archive and import libraries to different locations or gives them different names or something.

This is still true as of DPDK release 22.03.